# How to add Custom Settings for an AppExchange product programmatically?

Tags: apex, appexchange, customsetting

I installed an App Exchange product (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004cSsOEAU) and it allows one to set additional roles as part of custom settings.

While it can easily be done in the UI by going to Custom Settings for Chatter Delete, I wanted a programmatic way of doing it.

Looking at it, I can see that one can easily write some Apex code that does an upsert into the Chatter_Delete_Settings__c with the Profile Id. However where would I put this code as I am not familiar with seeding activities in Salesforce.

I mean it can be run as a post deployment step, but is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [InstallHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm) can do it, but that only applies to the original package developer. As a subscriber, the best you can do is a post-deployment step. Salesforce DX can help automate this (e.g. force:package1:install + force:data:bulk:upsert), but ultimately, you'd still need to do *something* to make this happen.